# Filtering collection using directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have three directives: schoolList (dropdown), groupList (dropdown), and searchBar (input).

There is a collection of students. It can be filtered by school, group or custom search string. The data fetching logic is inside the controller.

What would be the best and the cleanest way to filter this collection from those directives? Like changing school or group should trigger a new request to the server with additional query params for filtering.

Now I have this `getUsers()` method in my controller and pass the reference of it to every directive, so that on value change those directives call the method, while the params are stored in separate service `ParamStorage`. But somehow this does not feel right...

Removing all the directives (cause they are short and simple) and moving all the logic to the controller makes it huge and hard to manage.

Thank you.

Comment: It is not a good practice to send a get request to the server each time your search query is changed. Get all the data first and use angular filters.

Answer (score 1):

Move your `getUsers()` to some service/factory like:

```
app.factory('users', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var url = 'http://my.domain.api/users/';
    return {
        filter: function (params) {
            return $http.get(url, {...});
        }
    };
}]);
```

And in your controller, inject the factory and call function `filter` whenever the filtering parameters are changed.

If your total number of users is not many, you'd better retrieve all the users first (stored in the cache). And whenever the filtering parameters change, query the local cache instead of issuing new http requests.